# How to keep scroll position in SimpleModal dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog, scroll, modal-dialog, simplemodal

How is it possible to keep the scroll position of a scrollable div within a modal dialog when it is re-opened?

I modified the basic downloadable example of simplemodal as follows:

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
    <h3>Scrollable Modal Dialog</h3>
    <div style="width: 150px; height:100px; overflow: auto;">
        a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I tested this solution with Simple Modal and it works*

If you are using there Basic Dialog demo, just change out the `basic.js` file for this code. It just gets the `scrollTop` before the dialog closes, and resets it when the dialog reopens. We have to call the full selector for the div each time because of how SimpleModal works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var scrollTop = null;
  $('#basic-modal input.basic, #basic-modal a.basic').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
      onShow: function(){
        if(scrollTop !== null) $('#basic-modal-content > div').scrollTop(scrollTop);
      },
      onClose: function(){
        scrollTop = $('#basic-modal-content > div').scrollTop();
        $.modal.close();
      }
    });
  });
});
```